# Removing falsely filled rows in time series data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have 1-min time series data with event and duration columns. Sometimes events don't happen for a while but the last event is forward filled until the next event occurs. We know how many minutes each event is supposed to last, I want to remove the data points that are falsely forward filled.

This is what the data looks like:

```
df
datetime           event     duration
2020-01-01 0:00     x           3
2020-01-01 0:01     x           3  
2020-01-01 0:02     x           3  
2020-01-01 0:03     y           2
2020-01-01 0:04     y           2
2020-01-01 0:05     z           2
2020-01-01 0:06     z           2
2020-01-01 0:07     z           2
2020-01-01 0:08     x           5
...
```

As you can see at 0:07, the event column should be N/A but is filled with z until the next event occurs at 0:08, I want to make 0:07 into a N/A. The duration column tells you how many rows the event should be occurring.
How can I achieve this?

Edit: So I guess the idea is, check duration column, count how many times the event occurs at that time, if it occurs more than what is said in duration, make it NaN until the next event. x,y,z are all recurring events so they happen multiple times throughout.

Comment: Is each event uniquely identified? E.g. Is event x still occuring on 2020-01-01 0:08?

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo one of x,y,z or none occurs repeatedly throughout. so not uniquely identified. at 0:08 event "x" starts again for duration 5 minutes. but z starts at 0:05 and supposed to last 2 minutes, however since x starts at 0:08, the 0:07 time is filled with z again.

Answer (score 1):

With `df` your dataframe you could try the following:

```py
groups = df["event"].ne(df["event"].shift()).cumsum()
mask = df.groupby(groups).cumcount() >= df["duration"]
df["event"] = df["event"].mask(mask)
```

First identify the groups of connected `event`s in `groups` (check for a change in column `event` and `.cumsum` over the resulting bools). Then identify the inccorect `event`s by comparing the `.cumcount` per group with the `duration`: whenever the `.cumcount` is larger or equal to the `duration` it is not correct (`>=` because `.cumcount` starts with 0). Then `.mask` those postions in the column `event`.

Result for the sample:

```
             datetime event  duration
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00     x         3
1 2020-01-01 00:01:00     x         3
2 2020-01-01 00:02:00     x         3
3 2020-01-01 00:03:00     y         2
4 2020-01-01 00:04:00     y         2
5 2020-01-01 00:05:00     z         2
6 2020-01-01 00:06:00     z         2
7 2020-01-01 00:07:00   NaN         2
8 2020-01-01 00:08:00     x         5
```